# Laravel Blade Template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

I have a blade template which I extend and pass a page title.. The page title I store in my database.

when passing the page title variable to the layout I get the following:

> name); ?>

when I should get

> Art

See my blade template

```
<h1>@yield('title')</h1>
```

See my extended blade layout

```
@extends('templates.front')

@section('title', '{{ $category->name }}')
```

can anybody see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't use Laravel blade syntax when passing variables.

```
@section('title', $category->name)
```

Remember that anything inside `{{}}` or passed as a `@func()` variable is interpreted by PHP literally.

Answer (score 0):

Define A Blade Layout

```
 <title>App Name - @yield('title')</title>
```

Using A Blade Layout

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', 'Page Title')
```

//as per your requirement Page title is string therefore in '' ,
   but if u r using variable then u can directly write variable name

```
@section('title', $category->name)
```

Answer (score -1):

When you call your Blade view you have to use controller function or Route
in that function get your page title somehow then pass to your view
Ex  :

```
public function index()
    {
        $title = DB::table('')->where()->get();
        return view('home',compact('title'));
    }
```

then in your view you can use

```
{{$title}}
```